Why does "why is the juice blue" have to be "почему сок синий"?
Why does "why is the juice blue" have to be Почему сок синий?
Can I reverse the last two words?

You can, but it won't be a translation of the required English sentence.
I will give you a situation where the second version would be appropriate:

- Какого цвета сок ты выбираешь? 
- Я выбираю синий сок. 
- Почему (ты выбираешь) синий сок? Почему не красный сок?

So, in the modified version, you aren't asking about the color of the juice; you are asking about the reason to choose the specifically colored juice.

It depends what you put an emphasis on. In your example you're asking why an object has a certain property, so in full length the question could be "Почему сок имеет синий цвет?" Now, if you omit the obvious words "to have" and "color" you are left with just "Почему сок синий?".
If you swap words and ask "Почему синий сок?" you'd mean "Why blue juice?" instead of "Why is the juice blue?" From the grammar standpoint "синий" acts as an object the first example and as a modifier in the second.
In some cases (for example in poetry) or during speech you can actually swap the word order, but then you still have to put an emphasis on color using intonation or rhythm. This would make you sound more pretentious or archaic, but maybe this is what you want to achieve.

Because it it would be
Why the blue juice?

Синий is an adjective. If you swap the order, an adjective in front of a noun would be dependant on the noun, just like in English.
The phrase itself omit the verb. It might be considered a pseudogapping, I think? There is no mandatory auxilary in modern language. An "is" - "является, есть" is implied. But "является" got a different government, you would need to alter the case for it to be correct. The meaning of question is:
Почему (этот) сок  является  синим?
Why    the juice   is        blue?

That's an odd, tortured and unnatural phrase if grammatically correct. It stinks of machine translation or mathematician speech. Don't use that in dialog. It's a standard way to say it with "is" omitted and sometimes other verb phrases are omitted as well by using a long dash.
